# How to display all successful and unsuccessful request to an API in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I have an input in which I write the names of the characters through a comma Ricky, Marty, etc.

Accordingly, on each of the heroes, I make requests in a database and show results.

How do I display a list of successful and unsuccessful requests if the hero is not found?

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {

  const { name } = context.query;
  const nameArray = (name as string).split(',');

  const allRequest = nameArray.map((el) => axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${el}`));

  const charactersList = await axios.all(allRequest)
    .then(axios.spread((...response) => response.map((e) => e.data.results)));

  return ({
    props: {
      charactersList,
    },
  });
};
```

With this code, I just get the data from the database. And I need it

Ricky (data from input) --- data from database Morty (data from input --- data from database)

, etc and the list of which was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to wait for all promises to either resolve or reject (and avoid rejecting everything if one of them rejects).

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const { name } = context.query;
    const nameArray = Array.isArray(name) ? name : [name];

    const allRequest = nameArray.map((el) =>
        axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${el}`)
    );

    const charactersList = await Promise.allSettled(allRequest).then((res) => {
        // Iterate over all results, both successful or unsuccessful
        return res.map((result) => {
            // Returns response data if successful, or `undefined` otherwise
            // Handle this however you like
            return result.value?.data.results;
        });
    });
   
    //...
}
```

Note that you should avoid using `axios.all`/`axios.spread` as they've been [deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated).